# Can I create a policy to disable a computer or user at a certain time?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, group-policy

Windows domain.
We close at 5.
I've been asked to disable certain computers/users at 5:15.

I know how to restrict access to the file system on the hour, but
a) that doesn't give enough grace time or too much, and
b) doesn't restrict enough, it only cripples

Comment: Can you expand on "disable"? Probably this will be a combination of access control and endpoint management. Things like warning users to save and logoff, then forcing them out.

Comment: @Garrett Fair question. I think they would be open to anything from preventing the user from using Office to forcing them to log out.

Comment: With some network automation you might be to close the network ports that they use, or shut their port on the switch.

Answer (score 6):

No, but you can allow users to log on only during certain hours; the setting is in the user account properties in Active Directory:

[image]

You can also use a GPO to force users to disconnect if they are logged in when their logon window expires.

---

Update about granularity:

According to [this discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/545552d4-8daf-4dd8-8291-6f088f35c2a4/how-is-the-logon-hours-attribute-set-in-active-directory-windows-server-2008-r2-?forum=winserverDS), the Active Directory attribute which stores this settings doesn't allow for more than single-hour granularity, so it's not possible to specify lesser periods such as 15 or 30 mins, regardless of which tool you use to set it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this is what we are using now. Doesn't have fine enough granularity. If I set it to 5, they get crippled right away whereas 6 is pointless. Really need that 15 minute grace period. Is there a way to set this with Powershell? That way it could be on at 5:05 and shut off at 5:15.

Comment: No way, sorry; see edited answer.

Comment: Actually, you answered my question. I can run this at 5:15, set the closing hour back to 5, then GPO force disconnect.

Comment: Well, that's... *creative* for sure. Just look out for AD replication, especially if you have multiple sites.